# Renovate is not detecting helm charts name or version

Tags: helm3, renovate

This is the value in my helm `Chart.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v2
name: luna-lovegood
type: application
version: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  - name: application
    version: 0.8
    repository: https://luna-lovegood.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm
```

Whenever I run rennovate against this, I get this

```
Matched 1 file(s) for manager helmv3: deploy/helm/chart/Chart.yaml 
Name and/or version missing for all dependencies
```

Both name and version is present in `Chart.yaml`, I do not understand what is missing, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [renovate code](https://github.com/mattvaughan/renovate/blob/f3bdb9470c11da1194edc9e85d34231692dc1853/lib/manager/helmv3/extract.ts#L48) it was identified that renovate expects the value of "version" to be a string. So, by updating the Charts.yaml to:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: luna-lovegood
type: application
version: "0.1.0"
dependencies:
  - name: application
    version: "0.8"
    repository: https://luna-lovegood.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm
```

we were able to fix this issue.

Hope this helps, have a good day you debugging dev!